# SSMS RegEx replace with optional part

Tags: sql-server, regex, replace, ssms, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to separate columns into a separate line form "select", "group by" and "order by" keywords. How can I make the preceeding spaces optional?

**Find** (requires preceeding spaces):
`^{[ ]+}{(SELECT|GROUP BY|ORDER BY)} {[#_a-z0-5]+}`

**Replace with:** `\1\2\n\1  \3`

**Original query** (just an example with no logic):

```
SELECT myColumn
FROM  (
    SELECT myColumn
    FROM  foo
    GROUP BY myColumn
    ORDER BY myColumn
)   as  bar
GROUP BY myColumn
ORDER BY myColumn
```

**Result** (Failed for the main query):

```
SELECT myColumn
FROM  (
    SELECT
      myColumn
    FROM  foo
    GROUP BY
      myColumn
    ORDER BY
      myColumn
)   as  bar
GROUP BY myColumn
ORDER BY myColumn
```

**Expected result**:

```
SELECT
  myColumn
FROM  (
    SELECT
      myColumn
    FROM  foo
    GROUP BY
      myColumn
    ORDER BY
      myColumn
)   as  bar
GROUP BY
  myColumn
ORDER BY
  myColumn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of small changes to your regex gave the correct result for your example:

```
{^:b*}{(SELECT|GROUP BY|ORDER BY)} {.+}
```

`:b` matches space or tab. `*` matches zero or more occurrences (so keywords at the start of lines will be matched).
I didn't understand the purpose of the restriction on the column list names so replaced it with a generic `.+`, which seems more reliable.

This solution could probably be made more robust by not relying on a single space between the keyword and the column list:

```
{^:b*}{(SELECT|GROUP BY|ORDER BY)}:b+{.+}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use * quantifier after [ ] to make the preceding spaces optional. So the expression will be

```
^{[ ]*}{(SELECT|GROUP BY|ORDER BY)} {[#_a-z0-5]+}
```

and replace with same pattern you are using.

```
\1\2\n\1  \3
```